# save to external file, C

Tags: c, file, character, external

This is my code

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include"boolean.h"

           /*
            boolean ceksama(char c[20])
            {

              FILE *f;
              int retval;
              boolean same=false;
              char ccarray[20];
              int i,j;
              char cc;

            f=fopen("filepelanggan.exe","r");

            j=0;
            while(c[j]!='\0')
             {
                j=j+1;
             }

            retval=fscanf(f,"%c",&cc);
            while((retval!=EOF)&&(!(same)))
             {
                i=1;
                while(cc!='\0');
                  { 
                     retval=fscanf(f,"%c",&cc);
                     ccarray[i]= cc;
                     i=i+1;
                  }

                if(i!=j)
                  {
                      same=false;
                  }
                else
                  {
                      if(ccarray[i]=c[j])
                            {
                            same=false;
                        }
                      else
                        {
                             same=true;
                        }
                  }
            }

            fclose(f);
            return same;
            }

            */
```

---

```
            int main()
            {

              FILE *f;
              char nama[20];
              int retval;
              char c;
              int i=1;


            /*algoritma*/
            f=fopen("customerfile.txt","a");

            printf("\nenter your name:");
            scanf("%c",&c);

            /*
            if (!(ceksama))
            {*/

            while (c=='\n')
              {
                 scanf("%c",&c); 
              }

                            while (c!='\n')
              {
                  nama[i]=c;
                  i=i+1;
                  scanf ("%c",&c);
              }
            nama[i]=c;
            i=1;

                            while(nama[i] != '\n')
              {
                  retval=fprintf(f,"%c",nama[i]);
                  i=i+1;
              }
            fprintf(f,"%c",'\0');
            fprintf(f,"%c",'\n');

            /*}
            else
              {
                  printf("data has been registered");
               }*/
            fclose(f);

            }
```

In my code, I want to input a name and save it to an external file, which is to be checked with later name inputs, whether it the name already exists in external file or not

`main` is my main program, and above it the function to check if the name is already exist or not. But, the checking function I make in comment mode so the program can work properly.

The problem is, when I active the checking function, the program still can work
BUT
every time I try to input any name, already registered or not, it ALWAYS says registered, therefore, I can not store that name in external file

while I deactivate checking function(make into comment mode), the program work properly, it store name to external character. BUT didn't check if that name is already exist or not. therefore, the name may be store twice or more.

My algorithm to make this program is, when inputting name, it will read by character (because my teacher forbid us to use string or string.h). therefore i must store it to external file by each character. when checking, I also checked it by character, but it didn't work either

I declare `boolean.h` from my own

Comment: You really should compile with all warnings enabled, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux, and you should learn to use the debugger, e.g. `gdb` on Linux. Debugging skills are essential when coding C programs. Your `fprintf(f,"%c",'\0');` statement is probably wrong (why are you writing a null byte)? You could consider using `putc`

Comment: Also, please remove the commented code that is not essential to your question.

Answer (score 3):

to compare `ccarray` and `c`, you should use `strcmp`. You are in fact not even comparing but making an assignment ('=' instead of '==').
I am talking about line:

```
if(ccarray[i]=c[j])
```

Which should be:

```
if (strcmp(ccarray, c))
```

if I understand well your algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
but in this case, i cant use string.h, therefore, i cant use some function like strcmp or strlen etc( my teacher ask me not to use it, so this is part of spesification :( )

any ideas? have you tried to compile in your PC? sorry i just use windows, any ideas? :(

Comment: Then loop on all characters and compare using ==, don't assign using =